# Swift Ints and some Doubles working but not all Doubles

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

What I am trying to do is increase the rate that the method spawnEnemy() is called on, and it works well using the starred numbers as Ints, but I felt like it goes by way too quickly so I thought of using Doubles and using the decimal point. However, if I go into the tenths spot of subtracting an amount from spawnRate in
`self.spawnRate=spawnRate - 1.0` (I use anything but 0) spawnEnemy() will only be called on once in the simulator then nothing happens. Any advice or suggestions would be great. Thank you!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!

    var points: Int = 0

    var tickCount=0.0 //  **

    var spawnRate=15.0 // Spawn every 15 seconds to start with.....   **

    var spawnTimer:NSTimer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tickCount=self.spawnRate

        self.spawnTimer=NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("tick"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }

    func tick() {
        if (--tickCount == 0) { // **
            self.spawnEnemy()
            self.spawnRate=spawnRate - 0.5 // Change this to determine how quickly the spawn rate increases.....    **
            self.tickCount=self.spawnRate
        }
    }
    func randomPoint() -> CGPoint {
        let randomPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x:CGFloat(arc4random()%320),y:CGFloat(568-arc4random()%390))
        return randomPoint
    }

    func randomColor() -> UIColor {
        let red = CGFloat(drand48())
        let green = CGFloat(drand48())
        let blue = CGFloat(drand48())
        return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)
    }

    func spawnEnemy() {
        let enemy: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 160, y: 160, width: 100, height: 100))
        enemy.backgroundColor = randomColor()
        enemy.center = randomPoint()
        enemy.addTarget(self, action: Selector("buttonPushed:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(enemy)
    }
    func buttonPushed(sender : UIButton) {
        if sender.frame.height < 50 || sender.frame.width < 50 {
            sender.frame = CGRectMake(sender.frame.origin.x, sender.frame.origin.y, 50, 50)
            sender.backgroundColor = randomColor()
            sender.center = randomPoint()
            return
        }
        while sender.backgroundColor != UIColor.blackColor() {
            points = points + 1
            scoreLabel.textAlignment = .Center
            scoreLabel.text = "\(points)"
            scoreLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The simulator is not always very reliable and can produce behavior that is dissimilar to an actual iPhone. Always test on an actual iPhone when you can!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what's happening is you're trying to test a double with the equality operator. The problem is that there's always a bit of [complexity in how doubles are stored](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/doubles-are-not-floats-so-dont-compare-them/) that makes it very difficult to compare them with equality. Instead you need to do something like this:

```
if (--tickCount <= 0) {
```

That way you catch it going negative for sure, otherwise it can go right past 0 and continue to count down.

Comment: Even better, just make it `--tickCount < 1` to eliminate *any* ambiguity.

Comment: Oh, aren't unary `--` and `++` about to be deprecated in Swift 3? Better to just stop using them now.

Comment: I thought of that but then it would trigger on values between 0 and 1, which might be too early for the code. `<= 0` is more precise. And, [yes they are](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0004-remove-pre-post-inc-decrement.md).

Comment: Ok, thank you so much! That worked, but once the spawnRate hits 0 from really whatever number it is(15 - 0.5 (30x)) or (20 - 2 (10x)) it increases the speed so much. I kind of understand why this happens but I do not know how to just stop it. Any ideas? thx

Comment: Maybe instead of subtracting a set amount from `spawnRage` you could try multiplying it by some factor less than 1. If you use a value such as 0.8 it will fall off in a more controlled manner.

Comment: Oh, because it would slowly get smaller but still do the job, thanks. Ill try that